# Editing the entry in db, if the same entry already exists and then storing it in the db using php or sql?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a table in a database, the table contains a list of months, if we insert a new row *(Ex: `Jan`)*, and `Jan` is already existing in that table, then the new entry of `Jan` should be entered as `Jan2` and if again a `Jan` comes then it should be `Jan3`, is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can use a trigger for it.

Comment: You could write code for it?

Comment: I know the concept of trigger and trying to make a code for it

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a special command for this - [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

PostgreSQL has a thing alike - [INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html).

Many other DB have the same option.

Comment: I will try this code, but for now i have made changes in my db format to solve my query

Comment: Changes don't matter - these queries are independent of db schema.